# Socket.io 404 on nginx

Tags: node.js, nginx, socket.io

So I have been looking through a lot of posts, websites, and have still not gotten this problem fixed.

I have previously had a project running on my server, including socket.io, without problems.

But now that I am uploading this new project to the server, it seems that the socket.io always returns 404.

Sorry if I have overlooked something obvious here.

Nginx config:

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name localhost;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3001;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /demo/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /socket.io/ {
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
        proxy_pass_request_headers on;
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

My socket.io server:

```
const app = express();
const server = http.createServer(app);
const io = require('socket.io')(server);
server.listen(3000);
```

Client (Pug):

```
script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")
```

Note that the code above is what I have ended up with after reading through a lot of questions on here, on serverfault, aswell as blog posts several places.

I don't remember using a second location "tag" (is that what it is called?) for socket.io for the first one I used.

Comment: any updates on this?

Answer (score 5):

The proxy pass should be:

```
location /socket.io/ {
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/socket.io/;
  ... 
}
```

Please see https://medium.com/@ibraheemabukaff/how-to-proxy-websockets-with-nginx-e333a5f0c0bb for details...

Answer (score 0):

Giving your Nginx the server name `localhost` and then trying to `proxy_pass` to localhost is probably not going to do you any favours.

Try getting rid of the `server_name localhost;` entirely and changing all these:

`proxy_pass http://localhost:xxxx;`

to this:

`proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:xxxx;`

Or, if you want to do it properly then outside of your server block create an upstream directive:

`upstream socketserver {
    server 127.0.0.1:3000;
}`

and change your `proxy_pass` directives to:

`proxy_pass http://socketserver/;`

Comment: Hello, thanks for the answer.

Unfortunately, it does not work, and I still get a 404 when attempting to load socket.io.

Loading in the other site, but keeping this configuration actually works, so I am pretty confident it is a fault in my socket.io setup, but that seems to be the same too. (And it works locally).

Comment: Is it this file which is returning 404, or any connection at all to the socket server? `script(src="/socket.io/socket.io.js")`

Comment: It appears to be every connection, the file itself does not return a 404